# Form control valueChanges gives the previous value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a form control with name `'question1'` within the form object `parentForm` and I have subscribed to it in the following way.

Its a radio button with two options `Yes` and `No`, when I select `No` I get `Yes` and when I select `Yes` its a `No`.

```
this.parentForm.controls['question1'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  (selectedValue) => {
    // If option `No is selected`
    console.log(selectedValue);  // displays No. OK
    console.log(this.parentForm.value['question1']);  // displays Yes. Problem is here
  }
);
```

`selectedValue` variable has the correct value but if I do `console.log(this.parentForm.value['question1']` it gives the previous value.

I tried to put a `setTimeout()` before retrieving value from `this.parentForm.value['question1']`, It just works fine.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(this.parentForm.value['question1']); // gives the correct value.
}, 500);
```

But my question is why `parentForm` is not updated when its control's value changes and that too I am retrieving its value only after value was changed.

Note: I don't want to observe for `parentForm.valueChanges`, not my requirement.

Comment: So what prevents you from using `selectedValue`?

Comment: Using `this.parentForm.value['question1']` I can access it anywhere within the component. `selectedValue` has only local scope.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

`valueChanges` is an Observable so you can pipe `pairwise` to get the previous and next values in the subscription.

```
// No initial value. Will emit only after second character entered
this.form.get('fieldName')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => ... );
```

```
// Fill buffer with initial value, and it will emit immediately on value change
this.form.get('fieldName')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(null), pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => ... );
```

Example of it working in StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-vhtxua

**Update**

If you're noticing that `startWith` appears to be **deprecated** this is not the case.  There is only a single active signature for the operator, which you can read about in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61834849/1148107).

> Highly likely, you are using startWith(null) or startWith(undefined), they are not deprecated despite the notice, but IDE detects a wrong function signature, which is deprecated, and shows the warning.

A simple work around is providing the return type that would be expected:

```
// Prevent deprecation notice when using `startWith` since it has not been deprecated
this.form.get('fieldName')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(null as string), pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => ... );
```

Example of it working in StackBlitz with `startWith`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-rvxiua

Comment: pairwise should be the answer.

Comment: subscribe doesn't seem to fire when deleting a character using pairwise(). Example: My input box current is "96" and then I delete the "6" to have "9" in the input box, but the valueChanges.pipe.subscribe block doesn't execute.

Comment: @rharrison33 I'm not sure what is happening for you, but if you look at the StackBlitz I built for the answer it deletes and triggers a value change.

Comment: `startWith` seems to be Deprecated, solution still works fine as of the time of me commenting

Comment: @RicardoSaracino `startWith` is not deprecated

Comment: I've updated the answer to prevent the misconception that `startWith` is deprecated, and provided a link and quote from an answer found on StackOverflow so this answer remains on topic without unnecessary bloat.

Comment: I also updated the example at the bottom to the latest version and you can see that if you remove `as string` you get the deprecation notice as proof of it not being deprecated

Comment: @mtpultz, ahh my IDE did infact have a strike through it. Appreciate the update mate. Great answer

Comment: Do we need to unsubscribe from this subscription?

Comment: Be aware that `pairwise` -> emits on the second and subsequent
 * emissions from the source Observable, but not on the first emission, because
 * there is no previous value in that case.

Which is a pitty and could be substitued with a previous value of undefined or null imho.

Comment: @BernoulliIT I think you'll find example two takes that into account when you use `startWith(null)`, and you can see it work if you look at example two of the StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-vhtxua?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Chaka15 yes you must unsubscribe, otherwise you get a leak….

Comment: @Chaka15 yes, it's best practice to explicitly unsubscribe from the perspective of defensive programming.  You can create your own or just use the unsubscribe, but I tend to use https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy since it keeps things consistent.

Comment: Can we get the current value also? is there a way.  because with this what happened on the first time it's not changing the dropdown on very first selection?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @BernoulliIT have you got the any solution for this because in my scenario I need previous and current value but on the first emission it is not working expected ?

Comment: pairwise solve the issue for me. thanks

Comment: @RohitYadav this can be done with startWith(null/ 0/ 'something') as the answerer writes in the second example in the solution ☝

Answer (score 71):

The `valueChanges` event is fired **after** the new value is updated to the `FormControl` value, and **before** the change is bubbled up to its parent and ancestors. Therefore, you will have to access the value of the `FormControl` itself (which has just been patched), not a field of the `FormGroup` value object (which is untouched during the event).

In light of that, use `this.parentForm.get('question1').value` instead:

```
this.parentForm.controls['question1'].valueChanges.subscribe(
    (selectedValue) => {
      console.log(selectedValue);
      console.log(this.parentForm.get('question1').value);     
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. Any idea why the other method isn't working?

Comment: @AmitChigadani I've updated my answer to put in some explanation, please take a look.

Comment: The functionality described here is tagged as a bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13129

Comment: RxJS operators can manage the subscription result and extract prev and next without using the form control value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205373/1148107

Comment: not work any more....

Answer (score 7):

Try to do this

```
this.parentForm.controls['question1'].valueChanges.subscribe(
    (selectedValue) => {
      console.log(selectedValue);
      console.log(this.parentForm.value.question1);     
    }
);
```

if controls of FormBuilder was updated, you can immediately recover last values from FormBuilder object through the property value

Comment: This is very similar to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44898740/241211).

Comment: And this shouldn't be relied on as it is a hack that leveraging the way Angular changes are propagated. Please use RxJS pairwise operator

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option, but it might not be suitable in all cases: you can wait **[one tick](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick)** before the `selectedValue` is updated in FormControl:

```
setTimeout( () => console.log( selectedValue ) );
```

More on sync/async forms topic: [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#async-vs-sync) in Angular Guide docs.

Comment: don't use setTimeout if not really needed and here it's not really needed

Comment: This adds unneeded complexity and might cause undesired side effects. DON'T go this way 

Answer (score 1):

Don't use:

```
 this.parentForm.controls['question1'].valueChanges.subscribe
```

Use:

```
this.parentForm.get('question1').valueChanges.subscribe
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but this may help someone.

I had the following code:

```
attached to my fromGroup 

return new FormGroup({
   var1: new FormContol(''),
   var2: new FormContol(''), ...,
}, { validators: this.validateSelectedInputs, updateOn: 'blur' })
```

This was causing by form valueChanges to trigger on the 'blur' so the update for the value was only taking place after and would emit the previous value.