# How to get previous value of reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have form:

```
this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      type: [null, [Validators.required]]});
```

I listen changes:

```
this.filterForm.controls["type"].valueChanges.subscribe(
      selectedValue => {

});
```

In code above I get `selectedValue` of element, how to get previous value to make comparing like:

```
if (old("type") !== selectedValue) {
   // Call user method
}
```

I tried to do this with two others fields in form:

```
Observable.merge(this.filterForm.controls["classNumber"].valueChanges, this.filterForm.controls["classSuffix"].valueChanges).subscribe(response => {
        if (response[0] !== this.filterForm.value.classNumber && this.filterForm.controls["classSuffix"]) { // Call method }
    });
```

Comment: checkbox value?

Comment: No, select list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form control valueChanges gives the previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898010/form-control-valuechanges-gives-the-previous-value)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this method in order to achieve your concern:

Had created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-previous-formvalue) for your reference and check the stackblitz console

```
this.filterForm
   .controls["type"]
   .valueChanges
   .subscribe(selectedValue => {
       // New value of Type;
       console.log('New Value: ', selectedValue);

       // Old value of Type; Avoid using this.filterForm.get('type').value
       // This will give you the current/latest value.                 
       console.log('Old Value: ', this.filterForm.value['type']);   
});
```

Comment: Key comment is out of view of the code snippet - Avoid using this.filterForm.get('type').value - This will give you the current/latest value.

Answer (score 8):

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205373/3578809) to get previous value from reactive form. [Pairwise](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pairwise) puts the current and previous values together in one array and emits that.

Comment: *this.form.value['type']*
Did not work for me. The solution above did the trick.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

why not use a variable oldValue?

```
oldValue:any;
this.filterForm.controls["type"].valueChanges.subscribe(
      selectedValue => {
           console.log(selectedValue,oldValue);
           oldValue=selectedValue; //<--give value to oldValue;
});
```

Anyway, in a select valuesChanges happens only if you choose a new value (not if drop down is shown and select the value yet selected)