# Is the startWith operator in RXJS really deprecated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Since updating to RXJS version 6 my WebStorm editor has been complaining on *some* usages of [startWith()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) that the operator is marked as *deprecated*.

You can see in the source code that the methods are marked deprecated:

- [Link to master](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blame/master/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L7) ([Harder link for future](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blame/b24d3ea85d33b893e4c020fb4fa9f6fa4d05dc0b/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L7))

The problem for me is that the deprecated warning is not consistent. Sometimes it reports the method deprecated and other times it does not. While I can reproduce the warning in the below code examples. It seems to happen in my own source code randomly.

Not deprecated:

```
  of(false).pipe(startWith(true));
```

Is marked deprecated:

```
  const x: any = true;
  of(false).pipe(startWith(x));
```

So I am worried about these deprecated warnings. The deprecation message says to use `scheduled()` and `concat()` operators instead, but that feels like a more complicate alternative to an already handy operator like `startWith()`.

So I'm kind of confused as to why it's deprecated, but also why it's only deprecated sometimes.

Comment: No. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4772

Comment: @cartant ah. I see now. That should be answer if you want.

Comment: Pressed for time. If you could self answer your question, I'd appreciate it. I've added a note to my TODO list to improve the deprecation messages. And there's this issue, too: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4776

Comment: @cartant no problem. thanks for all the great work on rxjs.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, it is not.

Currently there is only one active signature: [startWith(...values)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/dfa239d/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L22)

Apart from this signature, it has several overloads which accept `scheduler: SchedulerLike` as the latest parameter: [startWith(...values, scheduler)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/dfa239d/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts#L6-L20) and this functionality has been deprecated.

**If you don't use `scheduler` with `startWith` you are fine.**

If you do, then you need rewrite your code using `scheduled` function like they suggest in the comment beside depreciation annotation: `scheduled([[a, b, c], source], scheduler).pipe(concatAll())`.

---

Highly likely, you are using `startWith(null)` or `startWith(undefined)`, they are not deprecated despite the notice, but IDE detects a wrong function signature, which is deprecated, and shows the warning.

Or, you are using `formControl.valueChanges` which emits `any` type, or any other observable stream with `any`. Because `any` matches the `SchedulerLike`, you see the notice.

Therefore, try to avoid `any` via adding `filter((v): v is number => typeof === 'number')` or any other possible way.

Comment: For others finding this when using `null` as start value the typescript compiler thinks you might be using the overload `startWith<T>(scheduler: SchedulerLike)` which is why there is a warning.

Comment: I've found that error using startWith(null) should I remove startWith in that case?

Comment: If you have the warning due to using startWith(null) or startWith(undefined), then the warning is erroneous and may be ignored. But you may fix it by casting null or undefined to some type. It may be some type of the related Observable, or just some unrelated type, e.g. startWith(<string>null). 
Edited: actually Anh-Thi DINH already [posted it below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971544/23715).

Answer (score 21):

For ones who see the deprecated warning in VSCode when you are using `startWith(null)`, just replace it with `startWith(<string>null)` in order to resolve the warning message.

More information is [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4772).

Answer (score 9):

One way to avoid the deprecation notice is by typecasting whatever you're passing into `startWith`. For example `startwith(x as boolean)` in the OP's example.

This way, you're reassuring your IDE that you're not using a deprecated signature.

Answer (score 2):

I also got a deprecated message when I was trying to `startWith(undefined)`
The reason is it's defaulting to
`export declare function startWith<T>(scheduler: SchedulerLike): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;` the deprecated API

The fix is specifying the return type `D`(of the undefined):
`export declare function startWith<T, D>(v1: D): OperatorFunction<T, T | D>;`

For example let's say I have Interface `MyType1` and my observable maps it to `myType2`:
`startWith<MyType1, MyType1>(undefined)`

Answer (score 1):

This trick works very well:

`startWith<void, void>(undefined);`

Comment: Getting this error for the mentioned approach, 
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<void, void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, void>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

My current alternative for a specific case (text input element) is to use an empty string `''`. It's also a falsy value. `startWith('')`. But the observable event is from type any. So null should also accepted. (Background: I use Angular Material "FormControl" valueChanges.)

Answer (score -1):

Replaced

```
startWith(null as any)
```

with

```
startWith<null, null>(null)
```

for better readability.