# RxJS 6.5.5 startWith deprecated. Alternative

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Update Angular to 9th version and occurred on `startWith` function stay deprecated. The documentation linked to `AsyncScheduler` class, but how to use it in my simple case I can't figure out:

```
private subscribeFilters(): void {
  this.filters.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(this.filters.value),
      pairwise(),
    )
    .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(prev) !== JSON.stringify(next)) {
        this.loadPage();
      }
    });
}
```

As you can see I'm using `startWith` for setting the filter initial state and exclude redundantly requests in the first time page load.

How I can implement the same logic without `startWith`. Perhaps as the documentation says with `AsyncScheduler` or another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61834849/9632621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the startWith operator in RXJS really deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571406/is-the-startwith-operator-in-rxjs-really-deprecated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `this.filters` or `this.filters.value` is `any`, that causes the issue because `any` matches `SchedulerLike`.

Try to type them correctly, then it won't be detected as `SchedulerLike` anymore and the notice should be gone.

Comment: what do you mean about `type them correctly`? When I use `startWith<any, any>` deprecation is gone but something like a hack.

Comment: I meant just `public filter: {value: string}`, something like that. But if generic works and removes the notice - it is also acceptable. The main goal is to let TS or Lint know that it's not `SchedulerLike` signature.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!