# Angular Reactive Form clone value

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular Reactive Form for the signup form.

```
 this.personalDataForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'username': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'address': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'mobile': new FormControl(null),
      'password': new FormControl(null),
    });
```

In this form I want it to be as when user types in the `name` field similar value get auto-filled to `username` field

But when a user types into the `username` field, the `name` field is unaffected.

Please let me know how to achieve this using Reactive Forms.

Comment: Where will the name and username be stored? also it depends on your use case. Are you referring to `this.form.valueChanges`? or a template variable? or a autocomplete field? Can you specify what you have written so far?

Comment: @ThomasCayne I have made some changes does it clear the confusion now

Comment: Aha! I understand now. I'll post my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep all your form manipulation logic in one place (in your TS file) which is the recommended way once you work with Reactive Forms.

Try this:

```
this.personalDataForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
  console.log('value has changed: ', x);
  this.personalDataForm.patchValue({ username: x });
});
```

To unsubscribe from the valueChanges check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893278/2050306

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvhfu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I was going to suggest this way, also. However, always remember to `unsubscribe()` or else we'll experience memory hog. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205373/4208845

Comment: @ThomasCayne Yes, unsubscribe is needed to avoid memory leaks. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ThomasCayne  why this answer is better than using a reference ?

Comment: `#nameTemplate` is a reference variable, as I answered below, and is the `simplest way` in this scenario when only `ONE` action is needed. Some people prefer the simple way. I used a mixture, and with custom directives when feasible, depending on the use cases. However, `form.valueChanges` can be used to do a combination of actions. For example, autocomplete, searching/sort, filtering, where a service will have to be called, to update a store, form, @Output(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template variable on `username` like so (simplest way):

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" #nameTemplate />

<input type="text" formControlName="username" [value]="nameTemplate.value"/>
```

Whatever you type in `name` field will reflect in the `username` field but not vice-versa. and the form will hold the value of `username`.